# How to prevent selection of past date in jdatepicker?

Tags: java, swing

I cannot find a way on how to prevent selection of past date in jdatepicker. can anyone help me please?

Comment: Please add some code on what you have tried so far.

Comment: I think it is not supported yet. But you can use JDateChooser insted.

Comment: oh shoot. how can i convert to JDateChooser now?

Comment: @CLT are you using visual component or creating it on runtime?